# Need Subquery or parameter pass through for sql or asp.net

Tags: asp.net, sql, asp-classic

I am trying to use the results from one recordset as the basis of a second recordsets results.
Q1 Gives me the correct summed inventory by part which I am attempting to pass into another query. (When I query the sum directly as part of Q2, the summed values are incorrect and seems to have something to do with the forecast table linkage.  Is it possible to create a subquery or pass the information directly.  (I am an intro user, so am not too familiar with processes)
Q1

```
oRS7.open "Select i.partNo, sum(i.InventoryQuantity) as 'Inv Qty in FG/FS' from invloc i Where i.InventoryLocation IN ('FG','FS') GROUP BY i.partno, i.InventoryLocation", oConn
```

Q2

```
oRS.open "Select p.PartNo, p.Description, [NEED THE RESULTS TO INSERT HERE], sum(m.ForecastQuantity) as 'Current Month Plan', sum(m.ForecastQuantity)/4 as 'Weekly Avg Plan', sum(m.ForecastQuantity)/30 as '1 Day Avg Plan',(case when i.InventoryQuantity < sum(m.ForecastQuantity) then 'Y' else 'N' end)as 'Below Monthly Plan',(case when i.InventoryQuantity < sum(m.ForecastQuantity/4) then 'Y' else 'N' end)as 'Below Weekly Plan',(case when i.InventoryQuantity <= sum(m.ForecastQuantity/30) then 'Y' else 'N' end)as 'Below 1 Day Plan'
from parts p, invloc i, salesforecast m Where p.PartNo = i.PartNo and p.PartNo = m.PartNo and i.InventoryLocation='FS' and m.ForecastDate between '" & Date & "' and '" & Date+27 & "' 
Group by p.partno, p.Description, i.InventoryQuantity, Order by 'Below 1 Day Plan' desc, 'Below Weekly Plan' desc, 'Below Monthly Plan' desc, p.PartNo ", oConn
```

The original coding called for one inventory but now I need to sum two inventory amts before comparing the values to the forecasted amts.  This is being pulled on an asp.net page from MS SQL Server

See original code below (need to take FG and make it a summed inventory)

```
<%@ Language="VBScript" %>
<%  Option Explicit %>
<%
    Response.Expires = 0
    Server.ScriptTimeout = 500000

    dim oConn, oRS, oRS2, oRS3, oRS4, oRS5, oRS6

    Set oConn = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")

    oConn.Open "Driver={SQL Server}; Server=ABSQL21; Database=DF_WHSE; Uid=ReadOnlyUser; Pwd=bionics;"

    Set oRS = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")

    Set oRS2 = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")

    Set oRS3 = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")

    Set oRS4 = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")

    Set oRS5 = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")

    Set oRS6 = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
%>
<html>

<head>
<title><%=Month(Date) & Day(Date) & Year(Date)%></title>
<style>
body  {
    font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Arial, Helvetica, san-serif;;
    font-size: 12px;
}
table {
    font-size: 11px;
    border-collapse:collapse;
}
td  {
    border-bottom: 1px #ccc solid;
    border-right: 1px #a1b0f3 dashed;
}
th  {
    border-bottom: 2px #333 solid;
    border-right: 1px #a1b0f3 dashed;
    background-color:#1790C0;
    color: #fff;
}
input  {
    border: 0px;
}
a  {
    color: #1790C0;
    text-decoration: none;
}
a:hover  {
    color: #5A6D81;
    text-decoration: underline;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<center>
<img src="Logo.png">
<br>

<%
    oRS.open "Select p.PartNo, p.Description, (case when i.InventoryLocation='FG' then i.InventoryQuantity else 0 end) as 'Inv Qty in FG', " &_
                "sum(m.ForecastQuantity) as 'Current Month Plan', sum(m.ForecastQuantity)/4 as 'Weekly Avg Plan', sum(m.ForecastQuantity)/30 as '1 Day Avg Plan', " &_
                "(case when i.InventoryQuantity < sum(m.ForecastQuantity) then 'Y' else 'N' end)as 'Below Monthly Plan', " &_
                "(case when i.InventoryQuantity < sum(m.ForecastQuantity/4) then 'Y' else 'N' end)as 'Below Weekly Plan', " &_
                "(case when i.InventoryQuantity <= sum(m.ForecastQuantity/30) then 'Y' else 'N' end)as 'Below 1 Day Plan' " &_
                "from parts p, invloc i, salesforecast m Where p.PartNo = i.PartNo and p.PartNo = m.PartNo and i.InventoryLocation='FG' and m.ForecastDate between '" & Date & "' and '" & Date+27 & "' " &_
                "Group by p.partno, p.Description, i.InventoryQuantity, i.InventoryLocation Order by 'Below 1 Day Plan' desc, 'Below Weekly Plan' desc, 'Below Monthly Plan' desc, p.PartNo ", oConn

    Response.Write "<table cellpadding=2 border=0 cellspacing=4>"
    Response.Write "<tr align=center>"
    Response.Write "<th width=50></td>"
    Response.Write "<th width=130><b>Finished Part No</b></td>"
    Response.Write "<th width=140><b>Purchased Part No</b></td>"
    Response.Write "<th width=200><b>Description</b></td>"
    Response.Write "<th width=100><b>FG Inventory</b></td>"
    Response.Write "<th width=250><b>Forward 4 Week MRP Demand</b></td>"
    Response.Write "<th width=200><b>Comments</b></td>"
    Response.Write "</tr>"

    IF oRS.EOF THEN
        Response.Write "<tr align=center>"
        Response.Write "<td colspan=7>No MRP Warnings Found.</td>"
        Response.Write "</tr>"
    ELSE
    END IF

    DO WHILE NOT oRS.EOF

    Select case oRS("PartNo").Value

        case "7095316-36J"
        case "7095316-37H"
        case "7095316-49H"

        case else

            IF oRS("Below Monthly Plan").Value = "Y" THEN
                IF oRS("Below Weekly Plan").Value = "Y" THEN
                    IF oRS("Below 1 Day Plan").Value = "Y" THEN
                        Response.Write "<tr align=center>"
                        Response.Write "<td width=50 bgcolor=""#FF3366"">"
                        Response.Write "<td><font style=""color: #0098DB; font-weight: bold;"">" & oRS("PartNo").Value & "</font></td>"
                        Response.Write "<td>"

                        oRS2.open "Select Component from dbo.bomli_all where BomId='" & oRS("PartNo").Value & "' and Quantity = '1.0000' Order By Component ", oConn

                        Do While Not oRS2.EOF

                            oRS3.Open "Select MakeBuyCode from dbo.parts where PartNo='" & oRS2("Component").Value & "' ", oConn

                            If oRS3("MakeBuyCode").Value = "B" Then
                                Response.Write "<font style=""font-size: 10px;"">" & oRS2("Component").Value & "</font><br>"
                            Else
                                oRS4.open "Select Component from dbo.bomli_all where BomId='" & oRS2("Component").Value & "' and Quantity = '1.0000' Order By Component ", oConn
                                Do While Not oRS4.EOF
                                    oRS5.Open "Select MakeBuyCode from dbo.parts where PartNo='" & oRS4("Component").Value & "' ", oConn
                                    If oRS5("MakeBuyCode").Value = "B" Then
                                        Response.Write "<font style=""font-size: 10px;"">" & oRS4("Component").Value & "</font><br>"
                                    Else
                                    End If
                                    oRS5.Close
                                oRS4.MoveNext
                                Loop
                                oRS4.Close
                            End If
                            oRS3.Close

                        oRS2.MoveNext
                        Loop
                        oRS2.Close

                        Response.Write "</td>"
                        Response.Write "<td>" & oRS("Description").Value & "</td>"
                        Response.Write "<td><font color=#FF3366><b>" & oRS("Inv Qty in FG").Value & "</b></font></td>"
                        Response.Write "<td>" & oRS("Current Month Plan").Value & "</td>"
                        Response.Write "<td><input type=text size=30></td>"
                        Response.Write "</tr>"
                    ELSE
                        Response.Write "<tr align=center>"
                        Response.Write "<td width=50 bgcolor=""#FF6600"">"
                        Response.Write "<td><font style=""color: #0098DB; font-weight: bold;"">" & oRS("PartNo").Value & "</font></td>"
                        Response.Write "<td>"

                        oRS2.open "Select Component from dbo.bomli_all where BomId='" & oRS("PartNo").Value & "' and Quantity = '1.0000' Order By Component ", oConn

                        Do While Not oRS2.EOF

                            oRS3.Open "Select MakeBuyCode from dbo.parts where PartNo='" & oRS2("Component").Value & "' ", oConn

                            If oRS3("MakeBuyCode").Value = "B" Then
                                Response.Write "<font style=""font-size: 10px;"">" & oRS2("Component").Value & "</font><br>"
                            Else
                                oRS4.open "Select Component from dbo.bomli_all where BomId='" & oRS2("Component").Value & "' and Quantity = '1.0000' Order By Component ", oConn
                                Do While Not oRS4.EOF
                                    oRS5.Open "Select MakeBuyCode from dbo.parts where PartNo='" & oRS4("Component").Value & "' ", oConn
                                    If oRS5("MakeBuyCode").Value = "B" Then
                                        Response.Write "<font style=""font-size: 10px;"">" & oRS4("Component").Value & "</font><br>"
                                    Else
                                    End If
                                    oRS5.Close
                                oRS4.MoveNext
                                Loop
                                oRS4.Close
                            End If
                            oRS3.Close

                        oRS2.MoveNext
                        Loop
                        oRS2.Close

                        Response.Write "</td>"
                        Response.Write "<td>" & oRS("Description").Value & "</td>"
                        Response.Write "<td><font color=#FF3366><b>" & oRS("Inv Qty in FG").Value & "</b></font></td>"
                        Response.Write "<td>" & oRS("Current Month Plan").Value & "</td>"
                        Response.Write "<td><input type=text size=30></td>"
                        Response.Write "</tr>"
                    END IF
                ELSE
                    Response.Write "<tr align=center>"
                    Response.Write "<td width=50 bgcolor=""#FFFF66"">"
                    Response.Write "<td><font style=""color: #0098DB; font-weight: bold;"">" & oRS("PartNo").Value & "</font></td>"
                    Response.Write "<td>"

                        oRS2.open "Select Component from dbo.bomli_all where BomId='" & oRS("PartNo").Value & "' and Quantity = '1.0000' Order By Component ", oConn

                        Do While Not oRS2.EOF

                            oRS3.Open "Select MakeBuyCode from dbo.parts where PartNo='" & oRS2("Component").Value & "' ", oConn

                            If oRS3("MakeBuyCode").Value = "B" Then
                                Response.Write "<font style=""font-size: 10px;"">" & oRS2("Component").Value & "</font><br>"
                            Else
                                oRS4.open "Select Component from dbo.bomli_all where BomId='" & oRS2("Component").Value & "' and Quantity = '1.0000' Order By Component ", oConn
                                Do While Not oRS4.EOF
                                    oRS5.Open "Select MakeBuyCode from dbo.parts where PartNo='" & oRS4("Component").Value & "' ", oConn
                                    If oRS5("MakeBuyCode").Value = "B" Then
                                        Response.Write "<font style=""font-size: 10px;"">" & oRS4("Component").Value & "</font><br>"
                                    Else
                                    End If
                                    oRS5.Close
                                oRS4.MoveNext
                                Loop
                                oRS4.Close
                            End If
                            oRS3.Close

                        oRS2.MoveNext
                        Loop
                        oRS2.Close

                    Response.Write "</td>"
                    Response.Write "<td>" & oRS("Description").Value & "</td>"
                    Response.Write "<td><font color=#FF3366><b>" & oRS("Inv Qty in FG").Value & "</b></font></td>"
                    Response.Write "<td>" & oRS("Current Month Plan").Value & "</td>"
                    Response.Write "<td><input type=text size=30></td>"
                    Response.Write "</tr>"
                END IF
            ELSE
            END IF

    End select

    oRS.MoveNext
    Loop

    Response.Write "</table><br>"

    oRS.Close

    oRS.open "Select p.PartNo, p.Description, " &_
                "(case when i.InventoryLocation='FG' then i.InventoryQuantity else 0 end)as 'Inv Qty in FG', " &_
                "sum(p.OrderPoint)as '4 Weeks Safety Stock', " &_
                "sum(p.OrderPoint/4)as '1 Week Safety Stock', " &_
                "sum(p.OrderPoint/4/30)as '1 Day Safety Stock', " &_
                "(case when i.InventoryQuantity < sum(p.OrderPoint) then 'Y' else 'N' end)as 'Below Monthly Safety Stock', " &_
                "(case when i.InventoryQuantity < sum(p.OrderPoint/4) then 'Y' else 'N' end)as 'Below Weekly Safety Stock', " &_
                "(case when i.InventoryQuantity < sum(p.OrderPoint/30) then 'Y' else 'N' end)as 'Below 1 Safety Stock' " &_
                "from parts p, invloc i " &_
                "Where p.PartNo = i.PartNo " &_
                "and i.InventoryLocation='FG' " &_
                "and p.PlanningType='OPN' " &_
                "and p.OrderPoint > i.InventoryQuantity " &_
                "Group by p.partno, p.Description, i.InventoryQuantity, i.InventoryLocation " &_
                "Order by 'Below Monthly Safety Stock' desc, 'Below Weekly Safety Stock' desc, 'Below 1 Safety Stock' desc, p.PartNo", oConn



    IF oRS.EOF THEN
    ELSE
        Response.Write "<table cellpadding=2 border=0 cellspacing=4>"
        Response.Write "<tr align=center>"
        Response.Write "<th width=50></td>"
        Response.Write "<th width=130></td>"
        Response.Write "<th width=140></td>"
        Response.Write "<th width=200></td>"
        Response.Write "<th width=100></td>"
        Response.Write "<th width=250><b>Order Point Level:</b></td>"
        Response.Write "<th width=200></td>"
        Response.Write "</tr>"
    END IF

    DO WHILE NOT oRS.EOF


    Select case oRS("PartNo").Value

    case "6015213-001"
    case "5060050008"
    case "8044213-001"
    case "9050050011"
    case "5023015-001"
    case else

        IF oRS("Below Monthly Safety Stock").Value = "Y" THEN
                IF oRS("Below Weekly Safety Stock").Value = "Y" THEN
                    IF oRS("Below 1 Safety Stock").Value = "Y" THEN
                        Response.Write "<tr align=center>"
                        Response.Write "<td width=50 bgcolor=""#FF3366"">"
                        Response.Write "<td><font style=""color: #0098DB; font-weight: bold;"">" & oRS("PartNo").Value & "</font></td>"
                        Response.Write "<td>"

                        oRS2.open "Select Component from dbo.bomli_all where BomId='" & oRS("PartNo").Value & "' and Quantity = '1.0000' Order By Component ", oConn

                        Do While Not oRS2.EOF

                            oRS3.Open "Select MakeBuyCode from dbo.parts where PartNo='" & oRS2("Component").Value & "' ", oConn

                            If oRS3("MakeBuyCode").Value = "B" Then
                                Response.Write "<font style=""font-size: 10px;"">" & oRS2("Component").Value & "</font><br>"
                            Else
                                oRS4.open "Select Component from dbo.bomli_all where BomId='" & oRS2("Component").Value & "' and Quantity = '1.0000' Order By Component ", oConn
                                Do While Not oRS4.EOF
                                    oRS5.Open "Select MakeBuyCode from dbo.parts where PartNo='" & oRS4("Component").Value & "' ", oConn
                                    If oRS5("MakeBuyCode").Value = "B" Then
                                        Response.Write "<font style=""font-size: 10px;"">" & oRS4("Component").Value & "</font><br>"
                                    Else
                                    End If
                                    oRS5.Close
                                oRS4.MoveNext
                                Loop
                                oRS4.Close
                            End If
                            oRS3.Close

                        oRS2.MoveNext
                        Loop
                        oRS2.Close

                        Response.Write "</td>"
                        Response.Write "<td>" & oRS("Description").Value & "</td>"
                        Response.Write "<td><font color=#FF3366><b>" & oRS("Inv Qty in FG").Value & "</b></font></td>"
                        Response.Write "<td>" & oRS("4 Weeks Safety Stock").Value & "</td>"
                        Response.Write "<td><input type=text size=30></td>"
                        Response.Write "</tr>"
                    ELSE
                        Response.Write "<tr align=center>"
                        Response.Write "<td width=50 bgcolor=""#FF6600"">"
                        Response.Write "<td><font style=""color: #0098DB; font-weight: bold;"">" & oRS("PartNo").Value & "</font></td>"
                        Response.Write "<td>"

                        oRS2.open "Select Component from dbo.bomli_all where BomId='" & oRS("PartNo").Value & "' and Quantity = '1.0000' Order By Component ", oConn

                        Do While Not oRS2.EOF

                            oRS3.Open "Select MakeBuyCode from dbo.parts where PartNo='" & oRS2("Component").Value & "' ", oConn

                            If oRS3("MakeBuyCode").Value = "B" Then
                                Response.Write "<font style=""font-size: 10px;"">" & oRS2("Component").Value & "</font><br>"
                            Else
                                oRS4.open "Select Component from dbo.bomli_all where BomId='" & oRS2("Component").Value & "' and Quantity = '1.0000' Order By Component ", oConn
                                Do While Not oRS4.EOF
                                    oRS5.Open "Select MakeBuyCode from dbo.parts where PartNo='" & oRS4("Component").Value & "' ", oConn
                                    If oRS5("MakeBuyCode").Value = "B" Then
                                        Response.Write "<font style=""font-size: 10px;"">" & oRS4("Component").Value & "</font><br>"
                                    Else
                                    End If
                                    oRS5.Close
                                oRS4.MoveNext
                                Loop
                                oRS4.Close
                            End If
                            oRS3.Close

                        oRS2.MoveNext
                        Loop
                        oRS2.Close

                        Response.Write "</td>"
                        Response.Write "<td>" & oRS("Description").Value & "</td>"
                        Response.Write "<td><font color=#FF3366><b>" & oRS("Inv Qty in FG").Value & "</b></font></td>"
                        Response.Write "<td>" & oRS("4 Weeks Safety Stock").Value & "</td>"
                        Response.Write "<td><input type=text size=30></td>"
                        Response.Write "</tr>"
                    END IF
                ELSE
                    Response.Write "<tr align=center>"
                    Response.Write "<td width=50 bgcolor=""#FFFF66"">"
                    Response.Write "<td><font style=""color: #0098DB; font-weight: bold;"">" & oRS("PartNo").Value & "</font></td>"
                    Response.Write "<td>"

                        oRS2.open "Select Component from dbo.bomli_all where BomId='" & oRS("PartNo").Value & "' and Quantity = '1.0000' Order By Component ", oConn

                        Do While Not oRS2.EOF

                            oRS3.Open "Select MakeBuyCode from dbo.parts where PartNo='" & oRS2("Component").Value & "' ", oConn

                            If oRS3("MakeBuyCode").Value = "B" Then
                                Response.Write "<font style=""font-size: 10px;"">" & oRS2("Component").Value & "</font><br>"
                            Else
                                oRS4.open "Select Component from dbo.bomli_all where BomId='" & oRS2("Component").Value & "' and Quantity = '1.0000' Order By Component ", oConn
                                Do While Not oRS4.EOF
                                    oRS5.Open "Select MakeBuyCode from dbo.parts where PartNo='" & oRS4("Component").Value & "' ", oConn
                                    If oRS5("MakeBuyCode").Value = "B" Then
                                        Response.Write "<font style=""font-size: 10px;"">" & oRS4("Component").Value & "</font><br>"
                                    Else
                                    End If
                                    oRS5.Close
                                oRS4.MoveNext
                                Loop
                                oRS4.Close
                            End If
                            oRS3.Close

                        oRS2.MoveNext
                        Loop
                        oRS2.Close

                    Response.Write "</td>"
                    Response.Write "<td>" & oRS("Description").Value & "</td>"
                    Response.Write "<td><font color=#FF3366><b>" & oRS("Inv Qty in FG").Value & "</b></font></td>"
                    Response.Write "<td>" & oRS("4 Weeks Safety Stock").Value & "</td>"
                    Response.Write "<td><input type=text size=30></td>"
                    Response.Write "</tr>"
                END IF
            ELSE
            END IF

    End select

    oRS.MoveNext
    Loop

    IF oRS.EOF THEN
    ELSE
        Response.Write "</table>"
    END IF

    oRS.Close


    Set oRS = Nothing
    oConn.Close
    Set oConn = Nothing

%>

</body>

</html>
```

`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This does not answer your exact problem but may assist in resolving some of the join issues.

**NOTE:**  this contains the line

```
AND m.liid = ????
```

The forecast table will *probably* need a filter or join on this column in order to be properly unique. (It depends on the data). This is a common problem when trying to correlate actuals and budgets. I hope this helps - post back and I will help futher. I suspect that if we used SQLFiddle this would be much easier!

```
    SELECT p.PartNo, p.Description, 
    IQ.FG_Qty, Iq.FS_Qty,
    sum(m.ForecastQuantity) as 'Current Month Plan',
    sum(m.ForecastQuantity)/4 as 'Weekly Avg Plan', 
    sum(m.ForecastQuantity)/30 as '1 Day Avg Plan'
    FROM
    -- parts is unique on partNo
    parts p
    -- salesforecast is unique on partno,liid
    INNER JOIN
    salesforecast m
    ON P.partNo = m.partNo
    AND m.liid = ????
    INNER JOIN
    (
    -- The subtable IQ is unique on partNo
    Select 
    i.partNo, 
    sum(case when i.InventoryLocation = 'FG' then i.InventoryQuantity else 0 end) as [FG_Qty], 
    sum(case when i.InventoryLocation = 'FS' then i.InventoryQuantity else 0 end) as [FS_Qty]
    from invloc i 
    Where i.InventoryLocation IN ('FG','FS') 
    GROUP BY i.partno
    ) IQ
    ON p.PartNo = IQ.PartNo 
    AND m.ForecastDate between '" & Date & "' and '" & Date+27 & "' 
    --- Here is where we join
    GROUP BY p.partno, p.Description, IQ.FG_Qty, Iq.FS_Qty
```

Comment: Worked like a charm, combined the last two answers you had (did not need the liid join to make it work and verified results all as expected.  Thank you for all of your help on this!

Answer (score 0):

If I just address purely the SQL part:

You want to mix this:

```
Select i.partNo, sum(i.InventoryQuantity) as 'Inv Qty in FG/FS' 
from invloc i 
Where i.InventoryLocation IN ('FG','FS') 
GROUP BY i.partno, i.InventoryLocation
```

with this:

```
Select p.PartNo, p.Description, 
[NEED THE RESULTS TO INSERT HERE],  sum(m.ForecastQuantity) as 'Current Month Plan',
sum(m.ForecastQuantity)/4 as 'Weekly Avg Plan', 
sum(m.ForecastQuantity)/30 as '1 Day Avg Plan',
(case when i.InventoryQuantity < sum(m.ForecastQuantity) then 'Y' else 'N' end) as 'Below Monthly Plan',
(case when i.InventoryQuantity < sum(m.ForecastQuantity/4) then 'Y' else 'N' end)as 'Below Weekly Plan',
(case when i.InventoryQuantity <= sum(m.ForecastQuantity/30) then 'Y' else 'N' end)as 'Below 1 Day Plan'
from parts p, invloc i, salesforecast m 
Where p.PartNo = i.PartNo 
and p.PartNo = m.PartNo 
and i.InventoryLocation='FS' 
and m.ForecastDate between '" & Date & "' and '" & Date+27 & "' 
Group by p.partno, p.Description, i.InventoryQuantity
Order by 'Below 1 Day Plan' desc, 'Below Weekly Plan' desc, 
'Below Monthly Plan' desc, p.PartNo
```

You add the first query as a subtable and join it in but you need to be careful of double countinng issues:

```
Select p.PartNo, p.Description, 
-- Here's your column
IQ.[Inv Qty in FG/FS],  
------------------------
sum(m.ForecastQuantity) as 'Current Month Plan',
sum(m.ForecastQuantity)/4 as 'Weekly Avg Plan', 
sum(m.ForecastQuantity)/30 as '1 Day Avg Plan',
(case when i.InventoryQuantity < sum(m.ForecastQuantity) then 'Y' else 'N' end) as 'Below Monthly Plan',
(case when i.InventoryQuantity < sum(m.ForecastQuantity/4) then 'Y' else 'N' end)as 'Below Weekly Plan',
(case when i.InventoryQuantity <= sum(m.ForecastQuantity/30) then 'Y' else 'N' end)as 'Below 1 Day Plan'
from parts p, invloc i, salesforecast m ,
-- Here's your query from above, aliased as IQ
(
Select i.partNo, sum(i.InventoryQuantity) as 'Inv Qty in FG/FS' 
from invloc i 
Where i.InventoryLocation IN ('FG','FS') 
GROUP BY i.partno
) IQ
----------------------------
Where p.PartNo = i.PartNo 
and p.PartNo = m.PartNo 
and i.InventoryLocation='FS' 
and m.ForecastDate between '" & Date & "' and '" & Date+27 & "' 
--- Here is where we join
and IQ.partNo = p.partNo
Group by p.partno, p.Description, i.InventoryQuantity, 
-- don't forget to group by
IQ.[Inv Qty in FG/FS]
Order by 'Below 1 Day Plan' desc, 'Below Weekly Plan' desc, 
'Below Monthly Plan' desc, p.PartNo
```

Comment: I suggest you run in this in SQL Server Management Studio and  verify. Then I suggest you create it as a view and just select from the view in your code. Also keep in mind that if you're building reoprts like this you can do it in SQL Server Reporting Services rather than building custom apps.

Comment: So after I updated, I now am receiving instead of the sum, two lines per item, one for inv FG and one line for FS

Comment: If you're not interested in the Inventory Location, remove it from the GROUP BY. I have edited the answer above. It's difficult to test and understand without seeing data though.

Comment: So now I have it displaying inventory qty sum correctly, thank you but now I am seeing a doubling effect in the sum(m.forecast). Whenever there is a summed inventory value, the m.forecast sum is doubling as well but displays correct when a part is only in one inventory.  How can I stop m.forecast sum from doubling?

Comment: Select p.PartNo, p.Description, IQ.[Inv Qty in FG/FS], sum(m.ForecastQuantity) as 'Current Month Plan', sum(m.ForecastQuantity)/4 as 'Weekly Avg Plan', sum(m.ForecastQuantity)/30 as '1 Day Avg Plan', (case when IQ.[Inv Qty in FG/FS] < sum(m.ForecastQuantity) then 'Y' else 'N' end) as 'Below Monthly Plan',(case when IQ.[Inv Qty in FG/FS] < sum(m.ForecastQuantity/4) then 'Y' else 'N' end)as 'Below Weekly Plan',(case when IQ.[Inv Qty in FG/FS] <= sum(m.ForecastQuantity/30)

Comment: then 'Y' else 'N' end)as 'Below 1 Day Plan' from parts p, invloc i, salesforecast m , (Select i.partNo, sum(i.InventoryQuantity) as 'Inv Qty in FG/FS' from invloc i Where i.InventoryLocation IN ('FG','FS') GROUP BY i.partno) IQ Where p.PartNo = i.PartNo and p.PartNo = m.PartNo and m.ForecastDate between '" & Date & "' and '" & Date+27 & "' and IQ.partNo = p.partNo and i.InventoryLocation IN ('FG','FS') Group by p.partno, p.Description, IQ.[Inv Qty in FG/FS]

Comment: Does that post mean you've solved it? What is the primary key of each table?

Comment: I believe the data is dumped from an ERP system without anything built on no primary keys or relationships defined.  i will verify though. as far as solving the question the quantities sum correctly but an unintentional side effect was the summing of the forecast.  i need to prevent that sum.I

Comment: Regardless if whatever constraints are in your database, you need to be able to make an assumption like 'parts is unique on partno' if you can't do this then yuo can't write a reliable report. Anyway let me think a little further. This is a trivial exercise when you understand the cardinality of the tables but I'm having difficulty grasping it right now

Comment: Does you forecast table have an inventory location it? or is the forecast just a total across all locations? Also you are filtering on inventory location FS in one part of the query - are you only interested in FS?

Comment: Also wondering whether it would be possible to use case or other method to display next to the sum column the individual values for fg and fs?

Comment: Salesforecast has columns partno, liid, forecast date, and forecastquantity. Primary key is a combination of partno and liid.  No inv loc in the table. Partno is primary in parts invloc primary is  partno invloc combination. I adjusted the original filter using in ('fg','fs') where it was left out originally

Comment: Actually the issue might be due to joining to invloc twice - my bad. Let me post something else to try.